# Azure Service Fabric Cluster Supported SKU's

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, virtual-machine-scale-set

I am unable to find the supported SKU's for the Reliability tiers of a Cluster Node. As we are having four types of tiers and no where I got the info which SKU needs to provide for each reliablity tier.

I tried started testing with full node SKU's which were specified in Microsoft documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity. Then also issue persists.

I wanted to get the list of SKU's which will supports Individual reliability tiers.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer here in MSDoc for [Service-fabric cluster capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity).

In the above Doc, the supported VM sizes for each dependability tier are stated in tabular format. For each reliability tier, you can use any of the supported VM sizes.

*Need to check below while choosing* `SKU` *for Service-fabric clusters:*

Mostly, the level of tolerance to faults and availability for your Service Fabric cluster is determined by the reliability tier you select (Bronze, Silver, Gold, or Platinum).

Moreover, you have to outline the requirements and then select the `SKU` from the above-mentioned SKU checklist. Because each VM series has unique capabilities and performance characteristics.

*Note:*

> Durability level is set per node type. If there's none specified, *Bronze* tier will be used. Production workloads require a durability level of Silver or Gold to help avoid data loss from VM-level infrastructure requests.

Based on my workload & requirements, I created a cluster with VM capacity as 5, durability tier is gold with the standard `VM_size` as shown:

[image]